# python re.compile() and re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

So I try to print only the month, and when I use :

```
regex = r'([a-z]+) \d+'
re.findall(regex, 'june 15')
```

And it prints : june
But when I try to do the same for a list like this :

```
regex = re.compile(r'([a-z]+) \d+')
l = ['june 15', 'march 10', 'july 4']
filter(regex.findall, l)
```

it prints the same list like they didn't take in count the fact that I don't want the number.

Comment: filter keeps the whole thing if bool(condition)=True all items in your list match and are thus kept

Comment: if each element is only one date use [re.sub(regex,'\\1',x) for x in l]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `filter` like this example:

```
import re

a = ['june 15', 'march 10', 'july 4']
regex = re.compile(r'([a-z]+) \d+')
# Or with a list comprehension
# output = [regex.findall(k) for k in a]
output = list(map(lambda x: regex.findall(x), a))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[['june'], ['march'], ['july']]
```

**Bonus:**

In order to flatten the list of lists you can do:

```
output = [elm for k in a for elm in regex.findall(k)]
# Or:
# output = list(elm for k in map(lambda x: regex.findall(x), a) for elm in k)

print(output)
```

Output:

```
['june', 'march', 'july']
```

Comment: Or just a list comprehension: `output = [regex.findall(x) for x in a]`

Comment: Great !! But now I have all the month in a list inside a list. How can I deal with it and put them in a simple list instead ?